# addFontWeightStyle NoSuchMethodException on TextView

Tags: android, material-design, androidx

I am using **Androidx** library for my project, And I want to set a **font** to **textview**, so when I am applying any font to any **Textview** components than system gives me

> TypefaceCompatApi21Impl: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: addFontWeightStyle [class java.lang.String, int, boolean]

this type of error in run time but app not getting crash.

So how to overcome this error.

**Note**: It will properly work on without android x dependency.

**Below my code:**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_tv_title"
        style="@style/font_work_sans_medium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="title"
        tools:visibility="gone"/>
```

**Here is the style**

```
<style name="font_work_sans_medium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/work_sans_medium</item>
</style>
```

I am also setting font by **programatically** like this

```
var typeFace: Typeface? = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.work_sans_bold)
    getTitleView().setTypeface(typeFace, Typeface.NORMAL)
```

still getting this error

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue as well.

Comment: I am currently getting error but it is originating from my call to ```setContentView(R.layout.x)```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For some research i found the solution might me helpful, actually i am using alpha dependency which is not stable so i downgrade the lib version of AndroidX

I am using this **dependency**

```
 implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha04'
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

you should use this instead of

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

Comment: Although @PerracoLabs mentioned the but has been reported, the version downgrade is the solution for now.

Answer (score 17):

The issue has been reported to the [Android team](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124274577) and seems to be a fix in place for a future release:

As per comment #25 below version works

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
```

Answer (score 8):

I delete this line from my xml file and now works without errors

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

is about **addFontWeightStyle** Mehtod which throw a NoSuchMethodException in API21 Impl

Comment: I have not used textStyle

Comment: This does work but that is not the solution since the problem is that we do want to use fontStyle.

Answer (score 5):

Just read the stack trace carefully - it's an issue with AndroidX. It seems that  `androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi21Impl()` attempts to resolve statically a method with signature `addFontWeightStyle(lass java.lang.String, int, boolean)` from some internal to the framework class `android.graphics.FontFamily` via reflection... and it turns out that method doesn't exist. I am having the same issue with `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView`. Not much we can do until Google fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it is happening when the method expected to be public (or if not existing, which I believe is not the case) and is not, according to Class.java method (look at the comment below):

```
private Method getMethod(String name, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, boolean recursivePublicMethods)
        throws NoSuchMethodException {
    if (name == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("name == null");
    }
    if (parameterTypes == null) {
        parameterTypes = EmptyArray.CLASS;
    }
    for (Class<?> c : parameterTypes) {
        if (c == null) {
            throw new NoSuchMethodException("parameter type is null");
        }
    }
    Method result = recursivePublicMethods ? getPublicMethodRecursive(name, parameterTypes)
                                           : getDeclaredMethodInternal(name, parameterTypes);
    ***// Fail if we didn't find the method or it was expected to be public.***
    if (result == null ||
        (recursivePublicMethods && !Modifier.isPublic(result.getAccessFlags()))) {
        throw new NoSuchMethodException(name + " " + Arrays.toString(parameterTypes));
    }
    return result;
}
```

I believe it is some kind of a bug in Androidx.

Comment: is there any solution for that?

Comment: Well, if I'm correct and it is a bug in AndroidX, than no. We'll have to wait for an update. You can try load the font programmatically. It might help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <style name="CutsomFontTextView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/yourfont</item>
</style>
```

And apply this theme to textview like below

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/menu_tv_title"
    android:theme="@style/CutsomFontTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="title"
    tools:visibility="gone"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your style parent is `@android:style/TextAppearance.Small` click on that . You will see only two item

```
<item name="textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>
```

So the error is correct . that style dont have `fontFamily` property inside it.

try changing your parent theme to

```
<style name="font_work_sans_medium" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
 <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/work_sans_medium</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to remove the last parameter when you set the typeface programatically?

```
getTitleView().setTypeface(typeFace)
```

instead of

```
getTitleView().setTypeface(typeFace, Typeface.NORMAL)
```

internally is using fontStyle

Comment: Yes, i am try with this code

getTitleView().setTypeface(typeFace)

but till not working

Answer (score 1):

New to coding here, but if you go into the toolbar via **Build**/'**Edit Libraries and Dependencies**' and click **Suggestions**, and click **update** against **androidx.appcompat:appcompat:X.X.X**, it will fix the error rather than doing it in the build.gradle file  :)